# Search Box not visible in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, find-and-replace

I am not able to see what I type in the search box of the find/replace window.

I tried resetting the Window > Perspective..
But that didn't work for me.

[image: ScreenShot of the Find]

Answer (score 0):

The Find dialog has been resized to be too small. Just resize the dialog to be larger and the missing fields will appear.

Comment: Thanks greg-449. That worked. :)